# How to make @Runwith to run custom annotation processor class?

Tags: java, junit, annotations

I want to write an annotation and an annotation processor class that processes the time required by a method to execute. This  method will contain code to process the custom annotation what I have defined. Now, below is the working code but it has a pitfall.  I need to write a main method in the class having custom annotation and then invoke the Annotation processor class, which I want to avoid. How to overcome this issue. What I want is whenever I add the `@Performance` method over a method it should calculate and give the time consumed by that method ? Can any one please tell how this can be achieved ?

Annotation -

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Performance {
    boolean active() default true;
}
```

AnnotationProcessor class
public class AnnotationProcessor extends Runner{

```
public void main(Class<?> clazz) {

    Long startTime, endTime;    

    for(Method m : clazz.getMethods()){
        if(m.isAnnotationPresent(Performance.class)){
            Annotation an = m.getAnnotation(Performance.class);
            try{
                Performance per = (Performance) an;
                if(per.active()){
                    startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                        System.out.println("---------------- Start time --------["+startTime+"]---------------");
                        m.invoke(clazz.newInstance());
                    endTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                        System.out.println("---------------- End time ----------["+endTime+"]---------------");
                        System.out.println("---------------- Time difference :"+(endTime-startTime));
                }
            }catch(Throwable t){
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public Description getDescription() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void run(RunNotifier arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

}

Test Class for customized annotation -

```
@RunWith(AnnotationProcessor.class)
public class CheckAnnotation {

    public CheckAnnotation(){}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        method();
        methodA();
    }

    @Performance
    public static void method(){
        for(int k=0;k<100000;k++)
        {
            for(int l=3;l<9000000;l++){
                //some code
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Writing code done !!!!");
    }

    @Performance
    public static void methodA(){
        for(int j=1;j<32434324;j++){
            // some code
        }
        System.out.println("Code execution done !!!!!");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

After brainstorming and doing some experiments got the required result. 
Please suggest if there are any better ways possible. There is change in the Annotation processor class only.

```
public class AnnotationProcessor extends Runner{

    public AnnotationProcessor(Class<?> clazz) {

        Long startTime, endTime;    
        for(Method m : clazz.getMethods()){
            if(m.isAnnotationPresent(Performance.class)){

                Annotation an = m.getAnnotation(Performance.class);
                try{
                        Performance per = (Performance) an;
                        startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                            System.out.println("---------------- Start time --------["+startTime+"]---------------");
                            m.invoke(clazz.newInstance());
                        endTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                            System.out.println("---------------- End time ----------["+endTime+"]---------------");
                            System.out.println("---------------- Time difference :"+(endTime-startTime));
                            System.out.println();

                }catch(Throwable t){
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public Description getDescription() {
        return Description.EMPTY;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(RunNotifier arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```